# Mac Pro Keyboard itunes Play/Pause

Tags: macos, itunes

I have now got a Mac Pro keyboard and it does not have the iTunes play/pause images on them, so obviously, it does not work. Any suggestions to map the F8 key to control iTunes?

Comment: How does the keyboard look like? Can you post the link to an image? It's not [this](http://images.apple.com/keyboard/images/hero_2.jpg) as depicted here http://www.apple.com/keyboard/?

Comment: What happens if you press F8? Nothing?

Comment: Yeah just the Old mac pro KB. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the external keyboard with a laptop, you can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). (It only works if there's at least one other keyboard that has the media keys.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No matter what keyboard you connect, you can use BetterTouchTool (free) to create your own custom shortcuts. iTunes Pause/Play is a possible action. This should be more flexible and versatile…

Comment: I would love to do that but I can't since I am on a Leopard PowerMac G5